# Fnd max float number in 2d array (whitout knowing the size of it) on C

Tags: arrays, pointers, malloc, max

I am trying to find a solution in a C programming
I have a 2d array, but i dont know its size
I can only access the array with a array view of [11][11]
The main idea is to find the peak of a mountain (max element)
So basically my 2d array is a map where each index is a float number, corresponding to the height of the mountain
I know i am out of the map when my float number is -1
That is what i was thinking to do, but i cant put it onto a code in a proper way
My solution is based on brute force approach

my basic idea was getting one 2d array formed by myview
what would give me a [11][11] array

then get a max value on that [11][11] array and store it.
next step i would generate another myview array using a loop.

i would apply same process here, to get a max value on that new array
then i would compare myfirst Max value with that second Max value

the value who have the biggest value would be stored on my max variable, with the location as well (point x and point y).

then i would run a loop again to create another myview array, and so on.

My plan to run on all possible [11][11]arrays is:

starting from running a loop for all the columns, but always keeping the rows 1-11

i know there is no more columns when all the values inside of my array [11][11] are -1.0

so when i find that array i would jump for next section of rows (12-23) for example

and again run for all columns.

i also could set a max value per set of a row (so at set of rows 1-11 the max value (peak) is 197.15 , then at set of rows 12-23 the max value (peak) is 397.15, for example)

i know will not be more rows when in my first set of columns i get the values inside of my array [11][11] -1.0000

so i would just need to get my biggest value on all set of rows, then i would get my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you have a two-dimensional array with two lines of eleven elements each, as you would get if you ran `int array[11][11];`? Then you can have two nested loops, one `for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)` and `for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++)` nested inside each other to loop over the individual elements of the two lines. You have a buffer variable that holds the maximum so far. In your loop you compare each element you're looping over against the buffer variable, and the new element becomes the new buffer variable if it's bigger than the existing one:

```
void main(void) {
    int array[11][11];
    int buffer = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; 11 < 2; j++) {
            if (array[i][j] > buffer) {buffer = array[i][j];}
        }
    }    
}
```